# Unhandled exception (nvoglv32.dll) during drawing (rift)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glsl, oculus

I'm actually working on making AR with the HMD oculus rift.
I'm not a pro on openGL and I'm sure it is the source of my problem.

I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x064DBD07 (nvoglv32.dll) in THING.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

It hapens during the drawing in  quadGeometry_supcam->draw(); that is in renderCamera(eye); :

```
  glDrawElements(elementType, elements * verticesPerElement,
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*) 0);// Stop at this line in the debuger
```

Here's the drawing code

```
  frameBuffer.activate();
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl::Stacks::with_push(pr, mv, [&]{
    mv.preMultiply(eyeArgs.modelviewOffset);
    pr.preMultiply(eyeArgs.projectionOffset);
      //renderCamera(eye); //If I uncomment this part, it crash
    renderScene(eye);
      //renderCamera(eye); //If I uncomment this part, it works but It's not what I want
  });
  frameBuffer.deactivate();
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  viewport(eye);
  distortProgram->use();
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  eyeArgs.distortionTexture->bind();
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  frameBuffer.color->bind();
  quadGeometry->bindVertexArray();
  quadGeometry->draw();
  gl::VertexArray::unbind();
  gl::Program::clear();
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
void renderScene(StereoEye eye) {
  GlUtils::renderSkybox(Resource::IMAGES_SKY_CITY_XNEG_PNG);
  GlUtils::renderFloorGrid(player);
  gl::MatrixStack & mv = gl::Stacks::modelview();
  gl::Stacks::with_push(mv, [&]{
  mv.translate(glm::vec3(0, eyeHeight, 0)).scale(ipd);
  GlUtils::drawColorCube(true); // Before this call renderCamera crash after it works
});
}

void renderCamera(StereoEye eye) {
  gl::ProgramPtr program;
  program = GlUtils::getProgram(
      Resource::SHADERS_TEXTURED_VS,
      Resource::SHADERS_TEXTURED_FS);
  program->use();
  textures[eye]->bind();
  quadGeometry_supcam->bindVertexArray();
  quadGeometry_supcam->draw();
 }
```

If I call renderCamera before  GlUtils::drawColorCube(true); it crash but after it works.
But I need to draw the camera before the rest.
I'm not going to precise drawColorCube because it use an other shader.
I suppose that the problem comes from something missing for the shader program. So here's the fragment and vertex shader.

Vertex:

```
uniform mat4 Projection = mat4(1);
uniform mat4 ModelView = mat4(1);

layout(location = 0) in vec4 Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord0;

out vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * Position;
  vTexCoord = TexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment:

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;

in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 vFragColor;

void main() {
  vFragColor = texture(sampler, vTexCoord);
}
```

(I want to draw the scene on the image of the camera).
Any idea?

Comment: Where and how are you initializing quadGeometry_supcam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Edited)*

I thought the problem was in `NULL` being passed as `indices` parameter to `glDrawElements()` here:

```
 glDrawElements(elementType, elements * verticesPerElement,
                GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*) 0);
```

The last parameter, `indices`, used to be mandatory and passing in `0` or `NULL` wouldn't work, because it would then try to read the indices from that address and would produce that error *Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*

But as *Jherico* pointed out, it is possible to have a buffer with indices bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY` and then the `indices` parameter is an offset into that buffer, not a pointer. Passing 0 then simply means 'no offset'. And Oculus Rift SDK apparently uses this method.

The program crashing with that invalid access to address 0x0 at the line with `glDrawElements()` therefore does not indicate that `0` should not be used, but that the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY` buffer is not initialized or enabled correctly. Probably because of an improper cleanup, as *Jherico* pointed out in his better answer.

Comment: Thx for your answer.
It's only a quad so theres only 4 vertice, need 6 indice for rendering with GL_TRIANGLE type. I'm not saying too much shit?
The code is from a sample that I'm using as base. So I dont master everything.

But do you have an idea why it works after drawColorCube is called?
Theres still nothing given in indices thou.

Comment: *quad so theres only 4 vertice, need 6 indice for rendering with GL_TRIANGLE type* -- Yes. Also there are even more efficient things like GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or GL_QUADS themselves. The function is made mostly for drawing a lot of the same primitives at once, for better performance.

About the second question, I guess it works when you draw the camera after your code because only there `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` is currenltly called. Without it enabled, the `glDrawElements()` just returns quickly, because it does not have any source to fetch the vertices from.

Comment: Your information is incorrect.  If you have a buffer bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY then the indices parameter is an offset into that buffer, not a pointer.  Passing 0 simply means 'no offset'

Answer (score 1):

You aren't cleaning up the GL state after you call `quadGeometry_supcam->draw();`.  Try adding these lines after that call

```
gl::VertexArray::unbind();
gl::Program::clear();
```